# How can I share the screen using Cefsharp.wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I want to allow screen sharing feature from my WPF app. I am using Cefsharp.WPF package.

I tried the below command line argument from my code

```
var settings = new CefSettings();
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream", "1");
```

But this shared the default screen and did not asked any options to share.
Also, the argument - "`use-fake-ui-for-media-stream`" is used I guess for automation testing, what argument do I need to use for development?

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: There is no support for displaying a dialog, using `use-fake-ui-for-media-stream` is the only option currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support yet provided for this package.
Alternative is to use command line argument - use-fake-ui-for-media-stream
This will share default screen.